# Datatables sorting financial data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables 1.10.7 and having an issue sorting a specific column.

The data is a combination of amount difference and percent difference. I would like to sort by the amount difference, but also would be curious how to sort by percentage as well.

So an example of the data is:

```
<td>4.75 (3.75%)</td>
<td>-3.92 (3.08%)</td>
<td>21.91 (11.59%)</td>
<td>-9.75 (16.44%)</td>
<td>-2.87 (1.37%)</td>
<td>2.76 (1.32%)</td>
<td>19.59 (7.88%)</td>
<td>19.67 (7.92%)</td>
```

My DataTables initialization code:

```
$('#table').DataTable();
```

What would be the best approach to sorting this column correctly? The default configuration sorts them completely out of order.

Comment: what do you mean by *completely out of order*, also, it would be good if you post your desired result

Comment: Yes, please describe how this should be sorted a bit more. Should it be sorted on the amount difference or on percentage? Or, will a greater difference ALWAYS lead to a greater percentage (and vice versa). We don't know what it's being compared to.

Comment: A greater difference will NOT always lead to a greater percentage gain. There is no correlation between each row. I would like to sort by the amount difference, but also would be curious how to sort by percentage as well =)

Comment: also @EnriqueZavaleta  it is sorting now using the first - 9.76 (16.46%),- 3.81 (2.99%),- 2.87 (1.37%),8.13 (6.61%),4.63 (3.66%),21.79 (11.52%), etc

Comment: What is your data source? Is it static HTML or you pull data via Ajax? Please show your DataTables initialization code.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com static      $('#table').DataTable({}); is all

Answer (score 0):

I have always created my own sorting functions for cases like this.

Firstly, create a function to sort your column data ascending:

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom-sorting-asc']  = function(a,b) {    
    var x = a.split('(')[0];
    var y = b.split('(')[0];
    x = parseFloat( x );    
    y = parseFloat( y );
    
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
};
```

Secondly, create a function to sort your column data descending:

```js
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['custom-sorting-desc']  = function(a,b) {    
    var x = a.split('(')[0];
    var y = b.split('(')[0];
    x = parseFloat( x );    
    y = parseFloat( y );
    
    return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

Finally, bind the functions to the appropriate column in your DataTable:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable( {
        "columns": [   
            { "sType": "custom-sorting" }   
        ]
    });
});
```

This example will bind the sorting functions to the first column in your table. If you need to bind them to the second column, you would use this code:

```js
$('#myTable').dataTable( {
    "columns": [ 
        null,
        { "sType": "custom-sorting" }   
    ]
});
```

This code example will sort by the decimal values (such as 19.59) and not the percentages.

Please see my demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vdvmrz9y/1/). If you click the table column header you will see the custom sorting taking effect. The sorting logic might not be exactly what you're after but hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTES**

I would strongly recommend to display amount and percentage in a separate columns for usability and functionality (sorting/filtering), that what tables are for. Also that way no additional programming would be required.

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) to target the column where the data is using zero-based index in [`targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) (`0` for the first column in my example) and define column data [`type`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type) (`num` for numeric sorting) and [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to use only first numerical portion of the string when sorting is performed (`type === 'sort'`).

For example:

```
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
     columnDefs : [
        {
          targets: 0,
          type: 'num',
          render: function(data, type, full, meta){
             if(type === 'sort'){
                data = parseFloat(data);  
             }

             return data;
          }
        }
     ]
  });
```

> **DEMO**

See example below for code and demonstration.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
     columnDefs : [
        {
          targets: 0,
          type: 'num',
          render: function(data, type, full, meta){
             if(type === 'sort'){
                data = parseFloat(data);  
             }
            
             return data;
          }
        }
     ]
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<thead>
   <tr><th>Data</th></tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr><td>4.75(3.75%)</td></tr>
   <tr><td>-3.92 (3.08%)</td></tr>
   <tr><td>21.91 (11.59%)</td></tr>
   <tr><td>-9.75 (16.44%)</td></tr>
   <tr><td>-2.87 (1.37%)</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2.76 (1.32%)</td></tr>
   <tr><td>19.59 (7.88%)</td></tr>
   <tr><td>19.67 (7.92%)</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```